# LINQ / VB.NET select distinct from dataset

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a single columned datatable inside a single tabled dataset.

I just want to convert this dataset to distinct rows. Here is my code, it gives compile error '.' expected. What am I doing wrong? (I tried adding the ., still same error). I know this is something stupidly obvious. PLZ Save me! ;)

Thanks much in advance!

```
Dim query = _
    From email In ds.Tables(0) _
    Select email.Field<string>("Email").Distinct()
```

EDIT: DOH! MIXING VB/C# SYNTAX HERE! I changed  to (Of String) and it works... BUT NOW 'query' is an ienumerable collection of characters... not a datatable... so how do I convert back easily without manually doing a loop?? Plz advise!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are applying the `Distinct` method to each string, not the result of the query. As strings are collection of character, you can apply extension methods to them too.

Put parentheses around the query:

```
Dim query = _
  (From email In ds.Tables(0) _
  Select email.Field(Of String)("Email")).Distinct()
```

Comment: result now gives me a '<distinctIterator>d_7a'1[System.String]... when I try to cast to list<string> or DataTable it throws invalid cast exception... ugh, i might as well stop wasting my time and just do the old dictionary unique route...!

Comment: ..but I wont give up, so please tell me what I'm doing so obviously wrong! thanks!

Comment: hmm... I changed the return result of the function to query.ToList() and it casted properly to list(of string). Still not the datatable I want, but will work good enough...

Comment: You can't just turn it into a DataTable. You would have to create the DataTable and populate it with data from the query. Possibly a DataAdapter might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the distinct values after getting the values into datatabale by:

```
dtFiltered = dtNotFiltered.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "RAMI_ISSA") 'Get distinct values (by stting the first parameter to True)
```